# Python pandas parse html table to get hidden values and links

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.x

This is a snippet from the page I am trying to parse with Pandas using Python:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>website</title><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/global.css'><META HTTP-EQUIV='Content-Type' CONTENT='text/html; charset=UTF-8'></head><body><script src="analyticstracking.js"></script>

</h3><table class='gene'><tr><th>header1<br>info</th>
<th><a href='useful.php#cods'>header2</a><br>info</th><th><a href='useful.php#cods'>header3</a><br>info</th><th><a href='http://www.somelink' target=link onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.somelink'); return false;">header4</a><br><span class='td'>info</span></th>
<th><a href='http://www.somelink' target=link onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.somelink'); return false;">header5</a><br><span class='td'>info</span></th>
<th>header6<br>info</th><th>header7</th><th>header8</th><th><a href='useful.php'>header9<br>info</a></th></tr>



<tr class='even'><td class='center'><form action='get.php' method='GET'>
    <input type='hidden' name='acc' value='value1'><input type='submit' value='value1'></form></td>
    <td>stuff</td><td>stuff</td><td>stuff</td><td>stuff</td><td class='center'><span class='dm' title='some extra info'>stuff</span> </td><td>stuff</td><td><a href='http://www.link1' target=ref onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.link1'); return false;">link1</a><br><span class='td'><a href='http://www.link2' target=ref onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.link2'); return false;">link2</span><br><span class='td'><a href='http://www.link3' target=ref onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.link3'); return false;">link3</span><br></td><td style='white-space:nowrap;'> <span class='gen' title='extra_info'>stuff</span>  <span class='gen' title='extra_info2'>stuff2</span>   <a href='http://www.out' target='out' title='Link to out' onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.out'); return false;"><span class='dbs'>out</span></a> </td></tr>

<tr class='even'><td class='center'><form action='get.php' method='GET'>
    <input type='hidden' name='acc' value='value2'><input type='submit' value='value2'></form></td>
    <td>stuff2</td><td>stuff2</td><td>stuff2</td><td>stuff2</td><td class='center'><span class='dm' title='some extra info'>stuff2</span> </td><td>stuff2</td><td><a href='http://www.link4' target=ref onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.link5'); return false;">link4</a><br><span class='td'><a href='http://www.link5' target=ref onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.link5'); return false;">link5</span><br></td><td style='white-space:nowrap;'> <span class='gen' title='extra_info'>stuff</span>  <span class='gen' title='extra_info2'>stuff</span>   <a href='http://www.out2' target='out2' title='Link to out2' onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.out2'); return false;"><span class='dbs'>out2</span></a> </td></tr>

<tr class='odd'><td class='center'><form action='get.php' method='GET'>
    <input type='hidden' name='acc' value='value3'><input type='submit' value='value3'></form></td>
    <td>stuff3</td><td>stuff3</td><td>stuff3</td><td>stuff3</td><td class='center'><span class='dm' title='extrainfo'>stuff3</span> </td><td>stuff3</td><td><a href='http://www.link6' target=ref onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.link6'); return false;">link6</a></td><td style='white-space:nowrap;'> <span class='gen' title='extra_info'>stuff3</span>  <span class='gen' title='extra_info2'>stuff3</span>  </td></tr>

</table>
```

There are hidden variables in the table (header 6 and header 9) that when you hover your mouse over, you can see the information:

[image: screenshot]

and when I try with Pandas, I get the following:

```py
with open ("/root/Downloads/adad.html", "r") as content_file:
    f = content_file.read()
dfs = pd.read_html(f)
dfs
```

[image: screenshot2]

My wish is to obtain the following:

```
[   header1info    header2info    header3info    header4info    header5info    header6info         header7          header8                header9info
0   value1         stuff          stuff          stuff          stuff          stuff(extra_info)   stuff            link1(http://link1)    stuff(extra_info) stuff2(extra_info2) out(http://out)
                                                                                                                    link2(http://link2)
                                                                                                                    link3(http://link3)
1   value2         stuff2         stuff2         stuff2         stuff2         stuff2              stuff2           link4(http://link4)    stuff(extra_info) stuff(extra_info2) out2(http://out)
                                                                                                                    link5(http://link5)  
2   value3         stuff3        stuff3          stuff3         stuff3         stuff3              stuff3           link6(http://link6)    stuff3(extra_info) stuff3(extra_info2)]
```

Is this possible using Pandas? If yes, how can I achieve the desired output?

Sorry, I am not expert when it comes to Pandas. I am not sure if there are also other ways to parse the information. The only thing that comes to my mind is to split lines and get the needed information but you can only imagine how fastidious it is ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### short answer: NO

`pd.read_html()` only reads the text generated on the html, not the elements with their attributes. To achieve what you want, you might want to use an HTML parser like bs4 instead, and then find the table `class='gene'`, then iterate through `<tr>` and `<td>` inside it. The code is something like below:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = r"""<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>website</title><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/global.css'><META HTTP-EQUIV='Content-Type' CONTENT='text/html; charset=UTF-8'></head><body><script src="analyticstracking.js"></script>

</h3><table class='gene'><tr><th>header1<br>info</th>
<th><a href='useful.php#cods'>header2</a><br>info</th><th><a href='useful.php#cods'>header3</a><br>info</th><th><a href='http://www.somelink' target=link onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.somelink'); return false;">header4</a><br><span class='td'>info</span></th>
<th><a href='http://www.somelink' target=link onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.somelink'); return false;">header5</a><br><span class='td'>info</span></th>
<th>header6<br>info</th><th>header7</th><th>header8</th><th><a href='useful.php'>header9<br>info</a></th></tr>



<tr class='even'><td class='center'><form action='get.php' method='GET'>
    <input type='hidden' name='acc' value='value1'><input type='submit' value='value1'></form></td>
    <td>stuff</td><td>stuff</td><td>stuff</td><td>stuff</td><td class='center'><span class='dm' title='some extra info'>stuff</span> </td><td>stuff</td><td><a href='http://www.link1' target=ref onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.link1'); return false;">link1</a><br><span class='td'><a href='http://www.link2' target=ref onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.link2'); return false;">link2</span><br><span class='td'><a href='http://www.link3' target=ref onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.link3'); return false;">link3</span><br></td><td style='white-space:nowrap;'> <span class='gen' title='extra_info'>stuff</span>  <span class='gen' title='extra_info2'>stuff2</span>   <a href='http://www.out' target='out' title='Link to out' onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.out'); return false;"><span class='dbs'>out</span></a> </td></tr>

<tr class='even'><td class='center'><form action='get.php' method='GET'>
    <input type='hidden' name='acc' value='value2'><input type='submit' value='value2'></form></td>
    <td>stuff2</td><td>stuff2</td><td>stuff2</td><td>stuff2</td><td class='center'><span class='dm' title='some extra info'>stuff2</span> </td><td>stuff2</td><td><a href='http://www.link4' target=ref onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.link5'); return false;">link4</a><br><span class='td'><a href='http://www.link5' target=ref onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.link5'); return false;">link5</span><br></td><td style='white-space:nowrap;'> <span class='gen' title='extra_info'>stuff</span>  <span class='gen' title='extra_info2'>stuff</span>   <a href='http://www.out2' target='out2' title='Link to out2' onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.out2'); return false;"><span class='dbs'>out2</span></a> </td></tr>

<tr class='odd'><td class='center'><form action='get.php' method='GET'>
    <input type='hidden' name='acc' value='value3'><input type='submit' value='value3'></form></td>
    <td>stuff3</td><td>stuff3</td><td>stuff3</td><td>stuff3</td><td class='center'><span class='dm' title='extrainfo'>stuff3</span> </td><td>stuff3</td><td><a href='http://www.link6' target=ref onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.link6'); return false;">link6</a></td><td style='white-space:nowrap;'> <span class='gen' title='extra_info'>stuff3</span>  <span class='gen' title='extra_info2'>stuff3</span>  </td></tr>

</table>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

table = soup.findAll("table", {"class": "gene"})
trs = table[0].findAll("tr")

headers = []
for th in trs[0].findAll("th"):
    headers.append(th.text)
rows = []
for i in range(1, len(trs)):
    tds = []
    for td in trs[i].findAll("td"):
        a = td.findAll("a")
        spans = td.findAll("span")
        inputs = td.findAll("input")
        ret = ""
        if len(a) != 0 or len(spans) != 0 or len(inputs) != 0:
            if len(a) != 0:
                for link in a:
                    ret += link.text + '('+link['href']+') '
            if len(spans) != 0:
                for span in spans:
                    if span.has_attr('title'):
                        ret += span.text + '('+span['title']+') '
            if len(inputs) != 0:
                for inp in inputs:
                    if inp.has_attr('value'):
                        if inp.has_attr('type'):
                            if inp['type'] == "hidden":
                                ret +=  inp['value']
        else:
            ret = td.text if td.text != '' and td.text != '\n' else "NaN"
        tds.append(ret)
    rows.append(tds)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = headers)

df
```

Comment: Thanks for your provided answer. I will wait a bit to see if someone can propose another answer before accepting it.

Comment: sure, you can checkout the [official docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html) if you aren't sure. Anyway, using bs4 parser isn't fastidious, you can extract information from html file with a clean structure (as long as the html is valid), and probably wouldn't take 10 lines of code.

Comment: Would you kindly provide a code of `bs4` that will work with my original post and print the desired output ?

Comment: Almost ! the values are still printing `NaN` for `header1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209938/discussion-between-zen-and-damzaky).